# Trying to convert comma delimited to pipe and get "Label not contained in axis error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a script to parse a csv file and it was working great until I realized the end result needed to be pipe delimited. I was told the easiest way to do that was add sep = '|' when reading the file. But now it is saying my headers are not contained in axis. Using python 3.6 Thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime

##Open the target file as a datatable
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jpe17a\\Desktop\\BE Patients\\Jumpstart template.csv', sep='|')

##looks at the first name column and if it is empty it deletes the row
df = df[pd.notnull(df['First Name'])]

## creates a new csv file with same data
newfile = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%y")
df.to_csv('PopulationEnrollmentJumpstartMRNRegistrationTemplate ' + newfile + '.csv', sep='|')
print(df)
##deletes phone and address2 column from oringinal file
df.drop (['Address 2'], axis=1, inplace = True)
df.drop (['Phone'], axis=1, inplace = True)

##saves original file
df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\jpe17a\\Desktop\\BE Patients\\Test.csv", sep='|')

##opens the new file
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jpe17a\\Desktop\\BE Patients\\PopulationEnrollmentJumpstartMRNRegistrationTemplate ' + newfile + '.csv', sep='|')

##These columns where added because they do not come with provided spreadsheet but are needed for jumpstart. The columns are auto populated
df2['Patient Assigning Organization'] = 'MyHFN'
df2['Program Name']  = 'Case_Management'
df2['Sub Program Name']  = 'Community'
df2['Enrollment Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD'] = time.strftime("%x")
df2['Enrollment End Date (YYYY-MM-DD)'] = ''
df2['Status Description'] = 'Active'

##re ordering columns and not including uneccessary columns to drop them 
df2 = df2[['MRN', 'Facility', 'Patient Assigning Organization', 'Program Name', 'Sub Program Name', 'Enrollment Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD', 'Enrollment End Date (YYYY-MM-DD)', 'Status Description', 'First Name', 'Middle ', 'Last Name', 'Birthdate', 'Gender', 'Street', 'Address 2', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', 'Phone']]


df2.to_csv('PopulationEnrollmentJumpstartMRNRegistrationTemplate '+timeStr+'.csv, sep='|')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Also need change `sep=','` or remove it in first  read_csv, because `sep=','` is default parameter.

---

It seems you forget `sep='|'` in :

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jpe17a\\Desktop\\BE Patients\\PopulationEnrollmentJumpstartMRNRegistrationTemplate ' + newfile + '.csv', sep='|'))
```

Also is necessary define it in `to_csv`:

```
df.to_csv('PopulationEnrollmentJumpstartMRNRegistrationTemplate ' + newfile + '.csv', sep='|'))

df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\jpe17a\\Desktop\\BE Patients\\Test.csv", sep='|')
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I accidently added it to the save instead, but I corrected it  and am still getting the same error. :-(

Comment: I added it to the to_csv but still getting the same error. It's like it cannot read it when using |, which the file is originally not in.

Comment: I have an idea - can you send me your input file to my email in my profile with desired output if data not confidental?

Comment: The data is patient info but I will come up with some dummy data and send it on. Thanks!

Comment: your suggestion to change the first sep = ',' worked perfectely!